# How to make a functional HTML5 navbar

Tags: html, css, nav

I’m trying to practice my HTML5 and CSS3 skills by making a navbar for my page, but I’m having a lot of trouble. I'm trying to use HTML5 semantic tags to make it, but none of them are looking how I want them to and it is a huge positioning mess. Could someone please tell me how I could make a functional navbar?

Here’s my HTML code for the whole navbar and header:

```css
body {
    margin:0;
}

#nav-plus-head-wrapper {
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
}

#topheader {

}

#topnav {
    background: yellow;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

.navli {
    display: inline;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: orange;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<section id="nav-plus-head-wrapper">

    <!--CODE FOR WEBSITE NAME-->
    <header id="topheader">
        <h1>Site</h1>
    </header>

    <!--CODE FOR TOP NAVBAR-->
    <nav id="topnav">
        <ul id="topnav-ul">
            <li class="navli"><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li class="navli"><a href="">About</a></li>
            <li class="navli"><a href="">Services</a></li>
            <li class="navli"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</section>
```

Comment: Hello! You should put your code in jsFiddle so that others can play around with it, making it easier to help you.

Comment: @Andrew Making a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is helpful, but I think “should” is overstating how necessary it is. You have to make sure people know that it’s better to put the code only in the question than only on jsFiddle.

Comment: Ok how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @user2647716 Go to [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/). Paste your HTML and CSS in the appropriate panels. Click Save, and you will be redirected to a unique URL. Link to that URL in your question right before or after your code. On that URL, people can see what your code looks like on the page, and edit that code right on that page.

Comment: ok thanks I will do that very soon.

Comment: What do you want to do with it? It looks like a good start to me... http://jsfiddle.net/QsVEY/ No issues that I can see

Comment: I mean you could do something like space out the navs if you want http://jsfiddle.net/QsVEY/1/

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to make a functional nav bar. you can buttons, divs, links, lists, or even a mix of them. I usually go with the simplest way.

here is a simple way with simple code that you can check and read to learn from it.

I hope this will help.

```css
* {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    scroll-padding-top: 100px;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background: #666699;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.navbar {
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.navBtn {
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.navBtn a {
    color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;
    z-index: -1;
    display: flex;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.homeSect {
    background: #0066ff;
    margin-top: 100px;
    height: 100vh;
}

.workSect {
    background: #33cc33;
}

.aboutSect {
    background: #ffcc00;
}
```

```html
</head>
  <header class="header" id="header">
    <nav class="navbar">
      
      <button class="navBtn homeBtn" id="homeBtn"> 
        <a href="#homeSect">Home</a>
        </button>
      <button class="navBtn workBtn" id="workBtn">
      <a href="#workSect">Work</a>
      </button>
      <button class="navBtn aboutBtn" id="aboutBtn">
      <a href="#aboutSect">About</a>
      </button>
    </nav>
    
  </header>
  
<body class="body">
    
    <div class="onscrolldiv" id="onscrolldiv"></div>

  <section class="homeSect section" id="homeSect">Home section</section>
  <section class="workSect section" id="workSect">Work section</section>
  <section class="aboutSect section" id="aboutSect">About section</section>
```

Comment: Oh My, I just realized this question is 9 years old. but why did I see it in my feed?

Answer (score -2):

first you need to reset all your html like this:

```
*, *:after, *:before {
outline: none;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

then you float your `<header id="topheader">` left  maybe it s a logo

```
#topheader {
float:left;
    color:white;
}
```

and you `<nav id="topnav">` right the main nav

```
#topnav {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    float:right;
}
```

now you can set you items like this

```
.navli {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    width:24%;
    height:100%;
    padding:20px;
    margin:0 0 0 1%;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AvHKT/1/